# How to find if any one use our commercial library in android

Tags: android, android-library

I am trying to create a simple library.I planned to release it is as paid version. Free version can use for 15 days. After 15 days they should buy the commercial version. I have write some logic to expire in 15 days automatically. But someone can edit that logic. So that they can remove that code. Now my question is how to find the apps which is used our library. Is it possible to fine that?

Comment: Keep expiration info in a remote server.

Comment: @bigdestroyer.. Is it possible to trace the apps??

Comment: Well... I guess you could. It depends on what you understand as trace. If you want to know what app is using your library, in some part of the code you could obtain its name from the context and send it to your own server, or something similar. But I don't now if it is a morally right thing.

Comment: My guess is that you can inserts a public variable to remain unchanged after the code obfuscation, and to decompile applications you suspect encapsulates your library and search for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can release your library as a native library (.so) written in c++.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

It's more difficult to decompile and change the behavior of .so file (but still possible).

Comment: So have to write it using c++?? And still possible. :-( .. Is it possible to trace the apps??